# Is it possible to view the logs that show up in App Center locally?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

I am working on a Xamarin app which logs some events to App Center. I was wondering if these events are stored anywhere locally, perhaps in the Event Viewer, in addition to sending them up to App Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure I found it.

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{app guid}_{app_code}\LocalState\Microsoft.AppCenter.Storage
```

It's a sqlite file, you can open it with [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

For errors, there's also:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{app guid}_{app_code}\LocalState\Microsoft\AppCenter\Errors
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the logs are stored locally on the device. But currently, the location is not public and there is no document mentioning where the location is. So you can't view the logs locally now.

Answer (score 1):

App Center SDK is open source, so you can easily find the location in source code:

- iOS, MAUI iOS, Xamarin.iOS, RN iOS, Unity iOS - [*NSApplicationSupportDirectory*/com.microsoft.appcenter/Logs.sqlite](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/blob/5c59dce0fc0242d3521ac4b540c2276f9efb65a5/AppCenter/AppCenter/Internals/Storage/MSACDBStorage.m#LL63C3-L63C3)
- Android, MAUI Android, Xamarin.Android, RN Android, Unity Android - [//data/data/Application-Package-Name/databases/com.microsoft.appcenter.persistence](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-android/blob/0d68a70690eba6e553cf351c14695ba9d1fbd5cb/sdk/appcenter/src/main/java/com/microsoft/appcenter/utils/storage/DatabaseManager.java#LL98C33-L98C49)
  (**Note**: The database path is creating by `SQLiteOpenHelper` using the context and database name)
- Windows Desktop - [Path.Combine(global::Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Microsoft.AppCenter.Storage")](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/blob/5d6936f1e58b39233750ea7689dce9ba6e54a6c2/SDK/AppCenter/Microsoft.AppCenter.UWP/Utils/Constants.cs#L24)
- UWP - [Path.Combine(LocalAppData, "Microsoft", "AppCenter", installId, "Logs.db")](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/blob/5d6936f1e58b39233750ea7689dce9ba6e54a6c2/SDK/AppCenter/Microsoft.AppCenter.WindowsDesktop/Utils/Constants.cs#L32)